# in $R^2$ L is the line y=mx. find an expression for T(x,y) where T is the projection on L along the line perpendicular to L.

Tags: linear-algebra

there's just one vague example in my book for how this works and it wasn't covered at all in lecture.

the example says $T:R^2 \mapsto R^2, T(a_1,a_2)=(a_1,0)$ and that $T$ is a projection on the x axis. no other information.

i'm trying to project on a line perpendicular to $L$, which is defined by $y=mx$. i guess i should define $P$ by $y={-1 \over m}x$ as the line which is perpendicular to $L$.

i don't know if i'm on the right track or how to proceed from here.

the answer to the last question may be related to this. it was about finding the equation for a reflection using the same $L$. for that i got $T(x,y)=({m^2x-2my-x \over -1-m^2},{2mx+m^2y-y \over 1+m^2})$. i think this is perpendicular to $L$ by definition and maybe i should be using this too.

Answer (score 2):

First, take a point (a,b) and write down the equation of the line through (a,b) with slope -1/m. Find the coordinates of the intersection of this line with the line y=mx. Then replace a by x and b by y, which should give the answer you need, if I have interpreted the question correctly. In old-fashioned language, you have found the foot of the perpendicular dropped from a point to a line.